The preset with name Some ("development") is not available. why Im'I facing this?
Im quite new here basically my object is to build a parachain. For that I have started with minimal-template in polkadot sdk. After cloning minimal-template I built the minimal-template-runtime after that when I tried to generate chain_spec.json using chain-spec-builder but doing that Im getting below error. Got stuck here need help.

There are many arguments I do not recognize from build spec subcommand. Where do you have the command from? Try "node-template build-spec --chain dev". Also here is the docu for the subcommand https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/node-template/#build-spec

The substrate node has presets for chainspecs that you can use. "dev" and "local" are predefined. You can define new chain argument in this impl:
impl SubstrateCli for Cli {
...
  fn load_spec(&self, id: &str) -> Result<Box<dyn sc_service::ChainSpec>, String> {
    Ok(match id {
        "dev" => Box::new(chain_spec::development_config()?),
        "" | "local" => Box::new(chain_spec::local_testnet_config()?),
        "live" => Box::new(chain_spec::empty_config()?),
        "empty" => Box::new(chain_spec::empty_config()?),
        path => Box::new(chain_spec::ChainSpec::from_json_file(
            std::path::PathBuf::from(path),
        )?),
    })
  }
...
}

I have defined a new "empty" variant. The actual values for the spec are usually defined in the chain_spec.rs file. They look something like this:
fn local_testnet_config() > Result<ChainSpec, String> {
...
serde_json::json!({
    "balances": {
    ...
    },
    "aura": {
    ...
    },
    "grandpa": {
    ...
    },
...

The "dev" chain is also defined in this file. You can create the chain spec with the command node-template build-spec --chain dev.
More information about hte build-spec subcommand: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/node-template/#build-spec
